# How to optimize this piece of code In c

Tags: c

I have piece of code in C which removes any duplicate character in a string .But i am doing it in two loops and would like it to optimize to one loop .

```
void removeDuplicates(char* ptr)
{
 int end = 1;
 int length = strlen(ptr);
 int current;
 int i;
 current = 1;
 for(end=1; end<length; end++)
 {
    for(i=0; i<end; i++)
    {
        if(ptr[end] == ptr[i])
        break;
    }
    if(i == end)
    {
      ptr[current] = ptr[i];
      current++;
    }
   }
   ptr[current] = 0;
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
  char str[256] = {0,};
  gets(str);
  removeDuplicates(str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 1;
 }
```

How can i do this in one loop

Comment: -1 for sloppy indentation and so much whitespace that there's scrollbar next to the code. Post a comment when you've formatted the code properly and I'll reconsider.

Comment: post your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in one pass with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char str[] = "p123h12p97h62p32h";    // Input string.
    int found[256];                      // Assumes 8-bit char.
    char *src, *dst;                     // Source and destination pointers.

    // Output initial value and set found flags to false.

    printf ("Before: [%s]\n", str);
    memset (found, 0, sizeof(found));

    // One loop, processing each source character in string.

    for (src = dst = str; *src != '\0'; src++) {
        // If not yet found, flag it found and transfer it, else do nothing.

        if (!found[(unsigned int)(*src)]) {
            found[(unsigned int)(*src)] = 1;
            *dst++ = *src;
        }
    }

    // Insert new end of string, then output it.

    *dst = '\0';
    printf (" After: [%s]\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

This removes duplicates in one single pass, using two pointers that advance independently through the string:

```
src
 |
 v
 p123h12p97h62p32h
 ^
 |
dst
```

The `src` pointer advances by one each iteration of the loop. A character is copied from `src` to `dst` and the `dst` pointer is advanced only if the character has not been seen before (using the `found` array). The output is:

```
Before: [p123h12p97h62p32h]
 After: [p123h976]
```

Note the `"assumes 8-bit char"` comment - this is fine where you know the character set is ASCII (or any other 8-bit character set) but it may not be portable to more exotic implementations. You just have to ensure that there are enough elements in the `found` array for all of your characters. For example, a 10-bit `char` type would need 1024 elements (`210 = 1024`).

Comment: Still two for loops are there!!

Comment: The first is just zeroing his flag array. Replace with memset if you prefer.

Comment: or just use initialize way of C.... Like I just edited.
Beside, this is two loops one after each other, still O(n) while the first way was loop in loop which is O(n^2)

Comment: Amit, the first was just to zero the found array and it's not nested anyway, so it's still an `O(n)` algorithm whereas the original was `O(n^2)`. Gaz, good point, updated to fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
void removeDuplicates(char* ptr)
{
    int exists[256] = {0};
    int end;
    int current = 0;
    int length = strlen(ptr);

    for(end = 0; end < length; end++)
    {
        if (exists[ptr[end]]) break;

        exists[ptr[end]] = 1;
        ptr[current++] = ptr[end];
    }

    ptr[current] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char str[256] = {0,};
    gets(str);
    removeDuplicates(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I initially thought of doing. Micro-optimization to use up less memory for the "char seen" array, otherwise it's the same idea as posted by others.

```
void removeDuplicates(char* src) {
    // Bitfield to remember which chars we 've seen, assumes 8-bit char type
    char bitfield[32] = { 0 }; // 32 * 8 = 256 bits

    char* dest = src; // initialize "output" ptr

    while(*src) {
        // Bitfield manipulation
        char ch = *src;
        int pos = ch >> 3; // ch / 8
        int bit = ch & 0x7; // ch % 8
        char mask = 1 << bit;

        // If char seen for first time, mark and write to "output"
        if(!(bitfield[pos] & mask)) {
            bitfield[pos] |= mask;
            *dest++ = ch;
        }
        ++src;
    }

    *dest = 0; // null terminator
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/xUH2Q)**.

Comment: new cloned version: http://ideone.com/wzWdF -- this one uses `fgets` for input and returns `0`.